# Need A Special Combinatorics Formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose there are $n$ urns arranged from the first to the $n^{th}$ and you have $n$ marbles. The marbles are to be allocated in the urns. For each allocation, the result may be represented as $\{f_{1},\cdots,f_{n}\}$ where $f_{k}$ is the number of marbles in the $k^{th}$ urn.

Consider a re-arrangement: sorting each allocation in a non-increasing order, that is
$$ \{f_{1},\cdots,f_{n}\} \rightarrow \{f_{(1)},\cdots,f_{(n)}\}$$ where $f_{(k)}\geq f_{(k+1)}$. Obviously $\{f_{(1)},\cdots,f_{(n)}\}$ is an image of $\{f_{1},\cdots,f_{n}\}$ under the mapping "$\rightarrow$'' from $\mathcal{F}$ to $\mathcal{F}_{\downarrow}$.

Question 1: What is the cardinality of $\mathcal{F}$?

Question 2: What is the cardinality of $\mathcal{F}_{\downarrow}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\mathcal{F}_{\downarrow}$ you are interested is the set of (integer) partitions. The cardinality of the set of all partitions of size n (which you do here) does not have an easy formula.

The set $\mathcal{F}$ is a different story; its cardinality is $\binom{2n-1}{n}$. Let me include how I got to this, since this is how I usually go about these things.

- Calculate the first few numbers by hand. Here, this resulted in 1 for n=1, 3 for n=2, 10 for n=3 and 35 for n=4.
- Search for this string of numbers in the online encyclopedia of integer sequences (oeis.org)
- Check whether you get a hit that makes sense. Here, it does, namely http://oeis.org/A001700
- Usually, at this point I would check whether I can actually prove the given formula by some sort of recurrence relation or something alike. Here, I am leaving this up to you.

Comment: The number of partitions is only the start of it.  You have to add up $\binom{n}{f_1,f_2,\dots,f_k}$ for each partition $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_k$.  It seems like you'd actually have to generate all the partitions, which is hopeless.

Comment: Not really understanding your comment here. By partitions, you mean partitions of $\mathcal{F}$ by distinct images $\{f_{(1)},\cdots,f_{(n)}\}$, right? If so, then I am not asking for "all partitions of size $n$". Intuitively I think it should have a clean formula - but hey, who knows, maybe not. If not, that would be a big surprise.

Comment: @saulspatz hmm you may be right ... the cardinality of $\mathcal{F}$ may not be $n^n$ ... let me think about it some more. Nevertheless the question remains valid: how many distinct ways are there for $\{f_{(1)},\cdots,f_{(n)}\}$?

Comment: @StudentofStatistics If you say there are $n^n$ ways to distribute the balls, then you are treating the balls as distinct.  If the balls are indistinguishable, then the answer is $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ by starts and bars.  Also, if the balls are indistinguishable then the answer is the number of partitions of $n$, and as Marco says, there isn't a simple formula.

Comment: I mean integer partitions, as in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) I understand that the sum of the f_i's is n, and you want those ordered.

Comment: Okay, guys, I have edited the question (into questions). Now you still think that there is no easy answer?

Comment: I also edited my answer to indicate that I answered the question about the cardinality of $\mathcal{F}_{\downarrow}$. The cardinality of $\mathcal{F}$ is a completely different question.

Comment: And also included an answer to your question about $\mathcal{F}$.